# filebeat can't get log written at php by "fwrite"

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

My filebeat can't get the log file that written on php by "fwrite"
Here is my php coding:

```
$date = date("Y-M-d");
    $log_path = JSON_LOG_PATH."_".$date."_".$eventid.".log";

    if (!is_file($log_path)) {
        # code...
        if( ($jsonLog=fopen ($log_path,"w")) === FALSE){
            return false;
        }
        $json_string = json_encode($log_json);
        if(!fwrite ($jsonLog,"[".$json_string."]")){ 
            fclose($jsonLog);

            return false;
        }
        fclose ($jsonLog); 
    } else {
        $json_string_all = file_get_contents($log_path);

        if( ($jsonLog=fopen ($log_path,"w")) === FALSE){
            return false;
        }
        $data_all = json_decode($json_string_all,true);
        array_push($data_all, $log_json);
        $json_string = json_encode($data_all);
        if(!fwrite ($jsonLog,$json_string)){ 
            fclose($jsonLog);
            return false;
        }
        fclose ($jsonLog);
```

And here is my filebeat config:

```
filebeat.prospectors:


- type: log

  paths:
    - /usr/local/nginx/xxx/accessLog.log


  fields:
    logIndex: nginx
    docType: nginx-access
    project: app-nginx

- type: log
  paths:

    - /usr/local/nginx/xxx/uploads/logs/*.log


  fields:
    logIndex: nginx
    docType: nginx-pro
    project: app-nginx

#----------------------------- Logstash output 
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["xx.xx.xx.xxx:5044"]
  ssl.certificate_authorities:  ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash.crt"]
  ssl.certificate:  "/etc/pki/tls/certs/filebeat.crt"
  ssl.key: "/etc/pki/tls/private/filebeat.key"
```

Filebeat can got nginx-access log easily but can't get "/usr/local/nginx/xxx/uploads/logs/*.log"(written in php) at all.
Anyone can give me som advise?thanks a lot!

Comment: Does filebeat give you any error?